# How Should I Use HTTP Clients For Multiple Connections?

Tags: dart, httpclient

For a Flutter web app, I'm using a package that creates its own HTTP client instance, communicating with some gateway.
Additionally I have my own server for the app.

Should I modify the package, to have both connections on the same instance?
Or should I have a HTTP client for every connection?

Answer (score 1):

The benefit of reusing an instance of `HttpClient` is that Dart can then let a connection to stay open for later reuse in case you are going to make another request against the same server.

So I would in general recommend reusing a `HttpClient` instance if possible, but here are no issue in having multiple instances of it. Especially if the two instances are used to connect to different servers.

There can be several reasons for having multiple instances like e.g. you want different connection settings (e.g. timeout, user-agent, different handling of certificates) for different endpoints.